# Getting unique value of second field using arcpy.da.SearchCursor?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I have a feature class and using arcpy.da.SearchCursor I'm getting unique values of a field (e.g. Name).  How can I use this method to get the associated row value of a different field (diff field = Name2)?

So far I use this to get unique values on only field Name:

```
values = [row[0] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("Name"))]
    uniqueValues = set(values)
    for value in uniqueValues:
```

When searching through the feature class how do I also get the value of another field, field Name2?

Comment: Can you provide a little more context? What are you looking to do exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dictionary comprehension:

```
{row[0]: row[1] for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("Name", "Name2"))}
```

Note this will only have ONE value per unique Name column value. You can also use collections to get a *list* of Name2 values:

```
import collections
names = collections.defaultdict(list)

for name1, name2 in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, ("Name", "Name2")):
    names[name1].append(name2)
```

Answer (score 2):

The help file on [SearchCursor (arcpy.da)](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000) has Code Samples at the bottom. The first SearchCursor example 1 shows how to grab a list of fields. Assign the row[0] and row[1] to variable names to use in your code.

Comment: @con, The list of fields .format row method did not work for, for value in uniqueValues:

Comment: @artwork21 Can you post the modified code as an edit to your additional question?